# How to invoke the same msbuild target twice with different parameters from within msbuild project file itself

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have the following piece of msbuild code:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DirA>C:\DirA\</DirA>
    <DirB>C:\DirB\</DirB>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyToDirA"
          Condition="Exists('$(DirA)') AND '@(FilesToCopy)' != ''"
          Inputs="@(FilesToCopy)"
          Outputs="@(FilesToCopy -> '$(DirA)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(DirA)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CopyToDirB"
          Condition="Exists('$(DirB)') AND '@(FilesToCopy)' != ''"
          Inputs="@(FilesToCopy)"
          Outputs="@(FilesToCopy -> '$(DirB)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(DirB)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CopyFiles" DependsOnTargets="CopyToDirA;CopyToDirB"/>
```

So invoking the target `CopyFiles` copies the relevant files to `$(DirA)` and `$(DirB)`, provided they are not already there and up-to-date.

But the targets `CopyToDirA` and `CopyToDirB` look identical except one copies to `$(DirA)` and the other - to `$(DirB)`. Is it possible to unify them into one target first invoked with `$(DirA)` and then with `$(DirB)`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to generate an ItemGroup containing the Dirs and then % on that.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Dirs Include="C:\DirA\;C:\DirB\">
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CopyFiles"
    Condition="Exists('%(Dirs)') AND '@(FilesToCopy)' != ''"
    Inputs="@(FilesToCopy)"
    Outputs="@(FilesToCopy -> '%(Dirs)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="%(Dirs)" />
</Target>
```

Or you can do 2 explicit calls:

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles">
    <MsBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Targets="CopyASetOfFiles" Properties="FilesToCopy=@(FilesToCopy);DestDir=$(DirA)" />
    <MsBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Targets="CopyASetOfFiles" Properties="FilesToCopy=@(FilesToCopy);DestDir=$(DirB)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="CopyASetOfFiles"
    Condition="Exists('$(DestDir)') AND '@(FilesToCopy)' != ''"
    Inputs="@(FilesToCopy)"
    Outputs="@(FilesToCopy -> '$(DestDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(DestDir)" />
</Target>
```

I haven't tested either syntax, but am relatively more confident of the second.

(The answer, if there is one, is in my Sayed Hashimi book on my desk - you'll have to wait until the first of:

1. Get the book
2. I get bored
3. Sayed finds this post and comes up with a brilliant tested answer)

Comment: Hi Ruben. Could you expand the ... in your response? I am not that familiar with parameterized targets to understand what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @mark: done. Reason I didnt do it before is twofold 1. Didnt have a nice editor to hand. 2. not sure on syntax of first sample. Hope this helps. Highly recommend the Inside MSBuild book

Comment: I think that there is a problem with solution no. 2. If your build script is invoked with specific properties from the command line, those properties are not passed when you use the <MsBuild> task.

Comment: I've replaced `$(MSBuildProjectFile)` with `$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)` to make it clearer that the CopyFiles target is forking another MSBuild to call the `Target` directly below *and hence (unless there are `InitialTargets` in play), the only target that will ever run is `CopyASetOfFiles`, which only requires the two `Properties` that are passed (viz. `FilesToCopy` and `DestDir`)*. The key thing that jumps out wrt polishing the answer for me is to `BuildInParallel="true"` and `%`-batch over the `Dirs` to make them parallelizable. Hope you agree with my reasoning and I'm not missing something!

Comment: @Pete: The main problem with solution #2 is that it's pointless frivolity if the only concern is to copy files and/or do anything that can be batched within the `Target` - the cases where one needs to have copy-and-paste-and-slightly-modify `Targets` or fork another MSBuild are a lot rarer than one might think -- i.e., #1 is more idiomatic :D

Answer (score 9):

As someone already mentiond the answer is batching.

Here are some links:

- [MSBuild Batching Part 1](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,5f1e0445-ce3d-4052-ba80-42fd19512d42.aspx)
- [MSBuild Batching Part 2](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,b721bc22-c375-4e1e-bcc9-512dd64096bb.aspx)
- [MSBuild Batching Part 3](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,cab57d7f-9d6e-4358-8491-dc033fb3bacc.aspx)
- [MSBuild RE: Enforcing the Build Agent in a Team Build](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,096a2e3f-fcff-4715-8d00-73d8f2491a13.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, what you want is called batching in MSBuild.  The

```
;%(Dirs.Identity)
```

Defined in the Outputs will cause this task to be executed for each item in the Dirs ItemGroup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="CopyFiles"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" 
   ToolsVersion="3.5">

<ItemGroup>
    <Dirs Include="C:\DirA" />
    <Dirs Include="C:\DirB" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyFiles"
    Inputs="@(FilesToCopy);@(Dirs)"
    Outputs="@(FilesToCopy -> '%(Dirs.Identity)%(Filename)%(Extension)');%(Dirs.Identity)" >
    <Message Text="%(Dirs.Identity)" />
</Target>

</Project>
```

Outputs:

```
Build started 8/19/2009 10:11:57 PM.
Project "D:\temp\test.proj" on node 0 (default targets).
  C:\DirA
CopyFiles:
  C:\DirB
Done Building Project "D:\temp\test.proj" (default targets).
```

Change the Message task to Copy task with the following condition and you are done:

```
Condition="Exists('%(Dirs.Identity)') AND '@(FilesToCopy)' != ''"
```